# How to convert date format from different country languages to numeric date format

Tags: javascript, php

example

`26/Veebr/2020` to `26/02/2020`

I have a problem to convert date from a different language to `dd/mm/yy`

Like:

`18/Helmi/2020` to `18/02/2020`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Would help if you could tell what languages you use. I would use split and a lookup table if I could not use the date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: @mplungjan  first example used `Estonian` and second-one used `Finnish`. (checked on google translate)

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. Do you know the language before converting, i.e. here is a Finnish date?

Comment: @Ash Show us what you've tried so far. Describe the thing exactly what you want. Is it only for Estonian and Finnish or more?

Comment: Estonian and Finnish is just an example. I want a solution for another  language also

Comment: It's ok. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

With PHP you can created arrays for different languages ​​with elements 'Month Name' => Number. With strtr() the month names are exchanged for numbers. The result can then be parsed with DateTime::createFromFormat.

```
$transEstonian = ['Veebr' => '02'];  //this for all

$strDate = '26/Veebr/2020';

$strDateNum = strtr($strDate,$transEstonian);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i",$strDateNum." 00:00");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');  //2020-02-26
```

This can be done with javascript similarly.